# Python function is somehow overwriting a parameter and failing on second iteration of the call

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm working on a project using python (3.7) and the kivy (1.11) garden mapview library, I have the following code in `mapping.py`

```py
import csv
import os
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarkerPopup
from civilpy.UI.libs.baseclass.locationpopupmenu import LocationPopupMenu


class Map(MapView):
    """Main Class for building apps in the application, inherits MapView"""
    # Function to retrieve the data from csv file and update map accordingly
    markers = []

    def get_values_for_map(self, *args):
        # get data from csv file
        with open(f"{os.getcwd()}/User/Maps/Templates/Map_Making_Template.csv") as read_file:
            data = list(csv.reader(read_file))

        # loop through data values
        for value in data:
            name = value[2]

            if name in self.markers:
                continue
            else:
                self.add_marker(value)

    def add_marker(self, value):
        """Function to add markers to the Map"""
        # Assign lat and lon to variables
        lat = value[0]
        lon = value[1]

        # Create the marker object
        marker = StructureMarker(lat=lat, lon=lon)

        # Add the Marker to the map
        self.add_widget(marker)

        # keep track of markers collected
        name = value[2]
        self.markers.append(name)


class StructureMarker(MapMarkerPopup):
    market_data = []

    def on_release(self):
        # Open up the LocationPopupMenu
        menu = LocationPopupMenu(self.market_data)
        menu.size_hint = [.8, .9]
        menu.open()
```

and in `mapping.kv`

```
#:import Map libs.baseclass.mapping.Map

<CivilPyMaps@Screen>
    name: 'Maps'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: "10dp"

        Toolbar:
            id: toolbar

        Map:
            zoom: 7
            lat: 39
            lon: -78

        Button:
            id: map_import
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Import data from file"
            on_release: Map().get_values_for_map()
```

When I run the code everything runs as expected in the get_values_for_map() function at first, however when the for loop at the end calls add_marker() it works fine on the first iteration, but on the second iteration the "value" parameter (which is supposed to be a list) has been overwritten by a StructureMarker object causing the script to fail. I can't figure out why the value parameter is getting overwritten and how to fix it?

I'm basing my code off a [tutorial from Dirk Sandberg](https://github.com/Dirk-Sandberg/FarmersMarketFinderTutorial/tree/master/part6) that I've modified, his original code runs fine when I run that, but I'm sure there's some aspect of OOP in python that I'm not understanding here.  Can anyone help me out with this?

The actual error I'm getting is `TypeError: 'StructureMarker' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: updated the original question, it's occuring at the `lat = value[0]` line on the second iteration of the add_marker() call

Comment: Is there any way to debug a kivy app? Can you just print values as the program progresses?

Comment: I'm debugging it using pycharm to go through the steps just before it fails, as I mentioned the app works up to the point of it crashing, and I've worked out what's causing the crash (calling the function with the incorrect parameters) I just can't figure out what's causing the parameters to be overwritten, I assume it's something I'm not understanding about OOP in python, but I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question but I actually got it figured out, I was inheriting the MapView class for my Map class and that has a builtin add_marker() function that was overriding the function defined in my Map class.  Thanks to those who commented on my question.